# how to check if a folder in s3 bucket exists or not in shell script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, sh, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a bucket named: bucket1. I have to check whether a specific folder which is equal to previous month exists or not.

So, for example I want to run the script from aws datapipeline today, at first it will check if the previous month folder in s3 exists or not using shellcommand activity.

I am using this but it's giving true for all cases.Can anyone please help in this?

```
#!/bin/bash

lastmonth='date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-1) -1 month" +%m'
newpath="s3://bucket1//2020/$lastmonth/"                     
echo "Path is : $newpath"

state='aws s3 ls $newpath'
if [ -z "$state" ]
then
     exit 1
else
    echo "Path exists"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Use `$( )` instead of single quotes on the `lastmonth` assignment. same for `state`  try also https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @Jetchisel did you mean ? lastmonth=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-1) -1 month" +%m)

Comment: Why do you wish to check this? Folders do not actually existing in Amazon S3. For example, you can copy a file to a non-existent path and the folders "appear" in the UI. If that file is then deleted, the folder "disappears". But they never actually existed. So, why are you wanting to check for the existence of a path?

Comment: actuallY i have dependency on the s3 directory. If the directory exists then I want to run a python script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

lastmonth=`date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-1) -1 month" +%m`
newpath="s3://bucket1//2020/$lastmonth/"                     
echo "Path is : $newpath"

state=`aws s3 ls $newpath`
if [ -z "$state" ]
then
     exit 1
else
    echo "Path exists"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL So basically my requirement is to check whether a specific folder exists in s3 or not because in AWS data pipeline I want to run a python script which has dependency on this s3 directory. The above code is basically checking whether the folder exists or not.If it doesn't exists then the condition code would be 1 and the DP will terminate.